# PHP slimframework GET request doesn't return anything

Tags: php, mysql, reactjs, get, slim

So I am using PHP slimframework (https://www.slimframework.com/) for just a simple API I need to use in my React application and I cannot get my query to work with these parameters, because $start_date and $end_date are not returning anything from GET request. This MySQL query works like it should, I already tested it with startDate and endDate I get back from my React app, the problem is that I cannot figure it out how to get data back from these GET requests to my $start_date and $end_date variables.

This is what my backend looks like (slimframework):

```
<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app = new \Slim\App;


$app->get('/api/date', function(Request $request, Response $response){
    $start_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_GET['startDate']);
    $end_date=date('Y-m-d H:i:s', $_GET['endDate']);
    // $start_date = $app->request()->params('startDate');
    // $end_date = $app->request()->params('endDate');
    // $start_date = $request->getAttribute['startDate'];
    // $end_date = $request->getAttribute('endDate');

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `datescalendar` where `date` BETWEEN '{$start_date}' AND '{$end_date}'";
    // $sql = "SELECT * FROM `datescalendar` where `date` BETWEEN '1525679047' AND '1526283847'";


    try{
        // Get DB Object
        $db = new db();
        // Connect
        $db = $db->connect();

        $stmt = $db->query($sql);
        $dates = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        // return $response->withJson($dates);
        echo json_encode($dates);
    } catch(PDOException $e){
        echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}';
    }
});
```

This is how I fetch data from API in my React app:

```
fetchNewDatesNext() {
    const startDate = this.state.startDate.unix();
    const endDate = this.state.startDate.add(1, 'week').unix();

    axios.get(`http://localhost/api/date?startDate=${startDate}&endDate=${endDate}`).then((response) => {
      this.setState(() => ({ data: response.data}));
    });
  };
```

Application is working like it should when I just query everything at once from database (`$sql = "SELECT * FROM datescalendar`)

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$startDate = $request->getQueryParam('startDate');
$endDate = $request->getQueryParam('endDate');
```

Also watch out with that query, it is vulnerable to SQL injection. You must use prepared statements. See https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared

Comment: Still doesn't work https://gyazo.com/a47b5e64763ea3aab39f88c59043ddd5 , I think I tried it before too, empty API: https://gyazo.com/65975574ddebd0ff83784adc251285ad . var_dump($startDate) and var_dump($endDate) both turn back NULL ( NULL NULL []).

Comment: In the second screenshot you are not passing any GET parameter to the API. The URL should read `localhost/api/date?startDate=1525679047&endDate=1526283847`

Comment: When I put in localhost/api/date?startDate=1525679047&endDate=1526283847 I get back correct data https://gyazo.com/9a0c991f646b2b5fb2cf55973bbb932a . Maybe there is something wrong in my react app logic? Here is how I fetch data in my app: https://gyazo.com/268d9a36911dce36bd3daa03e115d00c and this is what happens when I click on "Next Week" or "Previous Week" https://gyazo.com/ee452d5f7576a44169b15eacf6e10118 . As you can see the parameters do change..

Answer (score 0):

try getting your params with `\Request` slim class, like: `$paramValue = $app->request()->params('paramName');`.

You can read more about in [Here](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v2/request/variables.html), Slim v2 documentation

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, I already tried it too as you you can see above (it is just commented out). I am stuck with it since yesterday..

Comment: If you `var_dump($_GET)`, doesn't return nothing? Have you tried to request via postman?

Comment: var_dump($_GET) just returns array(0) { } [] with Response Status: 200 (OK)

Comment: Problem is definitely that $_GET just doesn't return everything, because if If I use query with fixed startDate and endDate like this $sql = "SELECT * FROM `datescalendar` where `date` BETWEEN '1525679047' AND '1526283847'"; then it works.. so frustrating

Comment: Just started a new slim 3 project and coded that 
`<?php
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->get('/[{name}]', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    var_dump($request->getQueryParams());
});` 

It worked normally.

Comment: Try using `$request->getQueryParams();`

Comment: $request->getQueryParams(); works only when I use fixed startDate and endDate in my query. Something must be wrong with how I get the data from parameters, but I have no idea what to change.

Answer (score 0):

```
$app->get('/api/somewhere', function( $request,  $response){

//Calling ..../api/somewhere?stuff=bob

// var_dump($_GET['stuff']);  // <= Bad way
//=> string(3) "bob"


//var_dump($request->getAttribute['stuff']);
//=> Notice: Undefined property: Slim\Http\Request::$getAttribute

//var_dump($request->getParam('stuff'));
//=> string(3) "bob"

var_dump($request->getParams());
//=> array(1) { ["stuff"]=> string(3) "bob" } 
});
```

i think your request are just empty

Comment: What can I do about it? How can I make my request not empty? Here is how my parameters change https://gyazo.com/ee452d5f7576a44169b15eacf6e10118 (every time I click next week or previous week).

Comment: waow... i see. Its very strange . May you can try without slim a pure call to a php dump of your GET . Otherwise, you can try /api/stuff/[{start}]/[{end}] syntaxe (slim router doc)

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the problem is with my React app side logic how these parameters are changed. I am getting back valid parameters, but not for the right week. Since I am only fetching 1 week of data at the time from API I am not getting back data for the right week. Thank you for help anyway!

Also, the correct way to get get query parameters for me are:

```
$startDate = $request->getQueryParam(‘startDate’);

$endDate = $request->getQueryParam(‘endDate’);
```